# Floor of the power of a radical

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, radicals, binomial-theorem, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Good morning Stack Exchange,

I have encountered a problem that I have no idea how to solve. This is what the question asks:

Determine how many integers $2000 \leq n \leq 2010$ are such that $7$ divides $\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}(1+\sqrt{2})^n\rfloor$.

I truely have no idea where to even start. I have looked online for a bit, and I have found similar problems which are solved by reducing the problem to one about linear recurrences. There is also a "trick" I have tried to apply which exploits the fact that $\sqrt{2}-1<1$, but it has all been in vain. The factor of $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$ thwarts all of my attempts. The only "answer" I can come up with is that the congruences modulo $7$ are probably in a cycle of period $7$, so the numbers satisfying the answer are about $1$ in $7$ i.e. $2$. Can anybody help me? A solution would be great, but even hints will be gladly received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned the right applicable tools.

- $a_n:=(1+\sqrt2)^n+(1-\sqrt 2)^n$ is always an integer and follows a nice recursion
- The disturbing $(1-\sqrt 2)^n$ is always sufficiently small and you know exactly when it is positive and when negative
- Note that $\frac{\sqrt 2}4a_n\approx \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}4 $ with manageable error (cf. above).

Comment: $a_{n+1}-a_n=\sqrt 2((1+\sqrt 2)^n-(1-\sqrt 2)^n)\neq \sqrt 2a_n$

Comment: @FabioLucchini Ups, indeed, but $\approx$ with an error $2\sqrt2(1-\sqrt2)^n)$ of (once again) manageable size and sign.

Answer (score 2):

To Hagen von Eitzen's answer, I would add the following consideration.
Note that there exists a ring homomorphism $\Bbb Z[\sqrt 2]\to\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z$ such that $\sqrt 2\mapsto 4$.
Consequently:
\begin{align}
a_n
&=(1+\sqrt 2)^n+(1-\sqrt 2)^n\\
&\equiv 5^n+4^n\pmod 7
\end{align}
for every $n\in\Bbb N$.
Since for $n\geq 2000$ we have
$$\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}(1+\sqrt{2})^n\right\rfloor=
\begin{cases}
\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}4&n\equiv 0\pmod 2\\
\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}4-1&n\equiv 1\pmod 2
\end{cases}$$
the required values of $n$ are $\{2003,2004,2005,2009,2010\}$.

---

The same values of $n$ can be obtained by using a recurrence relation.
For if $(1+\sqrt 2)^n=u_n+\sqrt 2v_n$ with $u_n,v_n\in\Bbb Z$, then $u_0=1$, $v_0=0$ and
\begin{align}
u_{n+1}&=u_n+2v_n\\
v_{n+1}&=u_n+v_n
\end{align}
Consequently, $\frac 14(a_{n+1}-a_n)=v_n$ and $v_n\bmod 7$ is a periodic sequence of period $6$ with values:
\begin{array}{c|cc}
n&u_n\bmod 7&v_n\bmod 7\\
\hline
0&1&0\\
1&1&1\\
2&3&2\\
3&0&5\\
4&3&5\\
5&6&1
\end{array}
By periodicity, we get:
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
n&u_n\bmod 7&v_n\bmod 7&\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}(1+\sqrt{2})^n\rfloor\bmod 7\\
\hline
2000&3&2&2\\
2001&0&5&4\\
2002&3&5&5\\
2003&6&1&0\\
2004&1&0&0\\
2005&1&1&0\\
2006&3&2&2\\
2007&0&5&4\\
2008&3&5&5\\
2009&6&1&0\\
2010&1&0&0
\end{array}

Comment: Are you sure? My level  in mathematics is not so advanced, but this is not the answer I get. Using Hagen von Eitzen's hits, $a_{n+1}-a_n = \sqrt{2}((1+\sqrt{2})^n-(1-\sqrt{2})^n)$ is an integer always divisible by $4$ and $\frac{1}{4}a_{n+1}-a_n$ is either floor or ceiling of what I'm looking for depending on $n mod 2$. Then I need either $a_{n+1}-a_n\equiv 0 mod 7$ and $n$ even or $a_{n+1}-a_n\equiv 4 mod 7$ and $n$ odd. Only times this happens is $n = \{2002, 2003\}$

Comment: @carfog: I also check my solution by numerical methods, hence I confirm you the values of $n$ are 2003, 2004, 2005, 2009, 2010. I added an alternative solution to my answer.